# Configure artifactory in gradle failed push pom file

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

I would like to configure gradle with plugin for artifactory to push Android libraries. I don't have any issue with pushing aar files, but when pushing the POM I receive 409.

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':artifactoryDeploy'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 409 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors:    The
> >     target deployment path 'test/path.../0.0/name-0.0.pom' does not match
> >     the POM's expected path prefix 'path.../0.0'

Current configuration:

```
artifactory {

    contextUrl = "url"
    publish {
        repository {
            // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            repoKey = 'test'
            username = "test"
            password = "test"
        }

        defaults {
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true
            // Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default)
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose there is an issue with adding  repoKey before path. How can I force artifactory plugin to add repoKey ("test") before path?

Comment: Please share more details. What's the URL you are using in "contextUrl"?

Comment: url is located in internal infrastructure:
https://test.artifactoryonline.com/sdk/mobile-sdk/

Comment: Awesome, so what do you have in `contextUrl` in the script?